# Retrieving data from Firebase with Swift 3.0 from a random child path

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve an array of items from a directory with a random folder using an existing array of strings as reference

My data looks like this:

```
 Items
  - RandomID
    -title : "text"
    -subtitle: "text"
```

So far this is what I have tried, but it isn't working:

```
var array = [String]() //array to use as reference
var returnedItems = [Item]() //array of item objects

func retrieveData()
 {
     for i in array
      {
        let ref = main.child("Items")
        let query = ref.queryEqual(toValue: i)
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let item = Item!

            if snapshot.hasChild("title")
             {
               item.title = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["title"] as? String
             }
            if snapshot.hasChild("subtitle")
             {
               item.subtitle = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["subtitle"] as? String
             }

            returnedItems.append(item)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("Item: \(self.returnedItems.map { $0.title})")

         })
     }
 }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to retrieve all children, you can just use a single listener (modeled after [this example in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events)):

```
var array = [String]() //array to use as reference
var returnedItems = [Item]() //array of item objects

func retrieveData() {
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let item = Item!
            if child.hasChild("title") {
                item.title = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["title"] as? String
            }
            if child.hasChild("subtitle") {
                item.subtitle = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["subtitle"] as? String
            }

            returnedItems.append(item)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("Item: \(self.returnedItems.map { $0.title})")
        })
    }
    // returnedItems will still be empty here, since the data hasn't
    // been loaded yet. See the note after this code snippet.
}
```

But note that reading the data will still happen asynchronously here, so `returnedItems` will still be empty when `retrieveData` returns.